# How can I use transition themes (e.g. EntranceThemeTransition) in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I created a Universal Windows Application that performed a basic transition between my MainPage and 3 other BasicPages. Each BasicPage had a Grid and I was able to animate the items in the Grid when it was loaded using EntranceThemeTransition in XAML. So good so far. The problem, however, is that I can't run this like a normal Windows application. My understanding is that it must be loaded as a Metro app in order to run. This is problem because I would like to run this program on a Windows 7 machine.

Now I'm re-creating the project in WPF, but I can't use EntranceThemeTransition like I did before. There is no TransitionCollection or EntranceThemeTransition in the XAML for VB.NET.

Is there some way to access this prebuilt transition or will I have to use a combination of DoubleAnimation on the *.Left property *.Opacity property?

Comment: Welcome to the Microsoft nightmare of leaving WPF behind.  When they invented Windows 8 and decided to make the new runtime for .NET, they literally stopped development on WPF.  So in short, you cannot mix and match any of the new stuff in WPF.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for answering.

So how would one go about creating a standalone Windows application that can take advantage of animated transitions? Will I have to code it myself using a timer? Is there something I can reference?


If possible, this would have to be compatible across Windows 7, 8, and 10.

Comment: In WPF you can do animations as it is built into the framework.  I believe there are many examples over on CodeProject as well as in the Microsoft Samples (just look up both on Google)